# Read HttpServletRequest request body in java

Tags: java, java-8

Im trying to read the request body using HttpServletRequest of below request.

[image]

Using below method

> String test =
>   request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));

But it always return an empty string. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Please use common-io IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());

Comment: I've tried that too.. But no luck..Still returning an empty string

Comment: If the request body is empty, then it simply means that it's already been consumed beforehand. For example, by a request.getParameter(), getParameterValues() or getParameterMap() call. Just remove the lines doing those calls from your code.

Comment: @Amit Thanks for your response. But the body is not been consumed before. This is the first line of the controller.

Comment: Can you try to put req.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8"); before reading the content please?

You can also try with InputStream body = request.getInputStream(); I hope it would work..thanks

Comment: What do you get if you call `request.getParameter("amount")`?

Comment: Have you solved this? Care to share what happened?